# jquery dialog button to do the same as asp.net mvc submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, user-interface, dialog

I have tried to figure out a way of letting a jquery dialog button called Create do the same as an asp.net submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

I am using jquery 1.3.2

I have come up with the following to let the dialog use the correct controller method.

```
       var url = '<%= Url.Action("Create1", "Home") %>';
       $.post(url,data, 
                            function(data) {
                                alert("Successful. Id for this client is " + data.ClientNo);
                                $("#CreateForm input").attr("value", ""); // Success
                            },
                            "json"); // DataType
```

However, the method requires a model parameter

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create1(ClientDetail client)
```

Looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ data parameter is a map or string sent to the server

I am wondering is it possible to convert a model into a map or string possibly using the .attr method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is make sure that your post data has the same names as the property values of `ClientDetail`. So if `ClientDetail` has two properties: `Name` and `Age`, then make sure that the data you post looks like this:

```
var data = { Name: 'ClientName', Age: 24 };
```

ASP.NET MVC's [`DefaultModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx) will bind the posted data to your `ClientDetail` object.

Answer (score 1):

See http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Jquery function:

```
$('#other').click(function() {
  $('#target').submit();
});
```

Comment: I think he is asking for an Ajax way, not a traditional post back one.
but anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest you to do is : let the signature accept all your parameters, and you on the  server side will construct your object, and save it to your data store.

consider the following one:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create1(string clientName, string clientTitle, int clientAge)
    {         
           var client = new Client()
                         {
                           name = clientName, 
                           title = clientTitle, 
                           age = clientAge, 
                           .., 
                           .., etc
                         } 
    }
```

let me know if this works for you, and don't forget to mark as answer if it really helped you

Thanks.

Comment: the model binder will do that for you  if the names match up to the property names

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this before, thank you and +a for the new info.